# 'Delays expected until November'; what ought they to say instead?

Tags: expressions, expression-choice

Where there are major roadworks on British roads you often see signs which say something like ***Delays expected until November***. Everyone knows what it means i.e. that between now and November, if you use this piece of road you can expect delays.

However the wording suggests that if it is now only July, that you could be sitting in crawling traffic for four months. It just sounds ridiculous and there ought to be a better form of words which could be used.

How could the wording be improved to encapsulate the proper meaning more succinctly?

Comment: No, if there were *one* delay lasting till November, the first word will be singular rather than plural.  You could have 2 delays of 2 months each, though.

Comment: "Road work until November.  May God Have Mercy on Your Souls"

Comment: I don't think the phrase "delays expected until November" is ambiguous.  The phrase indicates that one or more delays are expected to occur, and that the expectation should last until November.  "Delayed until November" would describe the scenario where you are stuck in traffic for four months.

Comment: It also means that there would be **no** real delays, only "expectations," for now, not until it is November. What do you say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roadwork until November / Expect delays

Comment: So simple really. I don't know why the UK Transport Department persists with 'Delays expected for six months'! Perhaps it is just to keep us amused whilst we are waiting!

Comment: Delays on the roads or a Delay in the end date of the repairs?

Comment: Why *expect*? What does that signify?

Comment: @Kris  As the French would say *En cas d'incendie, gardez votre sang froid*, literally 'In case of fire, keep your blood cold'. Perhaps 'Delays expected. Don't forget your blood-pressure medication'.

Comment: @Kris Actually, this is the phrasing you will find in parts of the US. It cautions drivers that construction or roadwork is ongoing and that time should be allowed for delays en route to your destination should you decide to take this road.